# Pip subprocess error: No matching distribution found for matlabengineforpython==R2020b

Tags: python, matlab, pip, anaconda

So, I'm trying to import an environment.yml file from one windows laptop to a windows pc. I enter the following command (conda env create -f environment.yml), and get the following error (at the end of the code). The imports fail when they reach the matlabengine package. Not sure why this is. Any thoughts? Thanks.

```
C:\Software\srv569>conda env create -f environment.yml
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 22.9.0
  latest version: 22.11.0

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda


Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
Installing pip dependencies: \ Ran pip subprocess with arguments:
['C:\\Software\\srv569\\Anaconda3\\envs\\research_projects\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-U', '-r', 'C:\\Software\\srv569\\condaenv.0oaiyh7x.requirements.txt']
Pip subprocess output:
Collecting absl-py==1.0.0
  Using cached absl_py-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (126 kB)
Collecting ansi2html==1.7.0
  Using cached ansi2html-1.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting argon2-cffi==21.3.0
  Using cached argon2_cffi-21.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting argon2-cffi-bindings==21.2.0
  Using cached argon2_cffi_bindings-21.2.0-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl (30 kB)
Collecting asttokens==2.0.5
  Using cached asttokens-2.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Collecting astunparse==1.6.3
  Using cached astunparse-1.6.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting attrs==21.4.0
  Using cached attrs-21.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (60 kB)
Collecting backcall==0.2.0
  Using cached backcall-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting beautifulsoup4==4.11.1
  Using cached beautifulsoup4-4.11.1-py3-none-any.whl (128 kB)
Collecting bleach==5.0.0
  Using cached bleach-5.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (160 kB)
Collecting brotli==1.0.9
  Using cached Brotli-1.0.9-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (365 kB)
Collecting cachetools==5.1.0
  Using cached cachetools-5.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (9.2 kB)
Collecting cffi==1.15.0
  Using cached cffi-1.15.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (179 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer==2.0.12
  Using cached charset_normalizer-2.0.12-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting click==8.1.3
  Using cached click-8.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
Collecting cycler==0.11.0
  Using cached cycler-0.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.4 kB)
Collecting dash==2.4.1
  Using cached dash-2.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (9.8 MB)
Collecting dash-core-components==2.0.0
  Using cached dash_core_components-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.8 kB)
Collecting dash-html-components==2.0.0
  Using cached dash_html_components-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.1 kB)
Collecting dash-table==5.0.0
  Using cached dash_table-5.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.9 kB)
Collecting debugpy==1.6.0
  Using cached debugpy-1.6.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (4.3 MB)
Collecting decorator==5.1.1
  Using cached decorator-5.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (9.1 kB)
Collecting defusedxml==0.7.1
  Using cached defusedxml-0.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting entrypoints==0.4
  Using cached entrypoints-0.4-py3-none-any.whl (5.3 kB)
Collecting executing==0.8.3
  Using cached executing-0.8.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting fastjsonschema==2.15.3
  Using cached fastjsonschema-2.15.3-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting flask==2.1.2
  Using cached Flask-2.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (95 kB)
Collecting flask-compress==1.12
  Using cached Flask_Compress-1.12-py3-none-any.whl (7.9 kB)
Collecting flatbuffers==1.12
  Using cached flatbuffers-1.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting fonttools==4.33.3
  Using cached fonttools-4.33.3-py3-none-any.whl (930 kB)
Collecting gast==0.4.0
  Using cached gast-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (9.8 kB)
Collecting glob2==0.7
  Using cached glob2-0.7.tar.gz (10 kB)
Collecting google-auth==2.6.6
  Using cached google_auth-2.6.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (156 kB)
Collecting google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.6
  Using cached google_auth_oauthlib-0.4.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting google-pasta==0.2.0
  Using cached google_pasta-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
Collecting grpcio==1.46.3
  Using cached grpcio-1.46.3-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (3.5 MB)
Collecting h5py==3.7.0
  Using cached h5py-3.7.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (2.6 MB)
Collecting idna==3.3
  Using cached idna-3.3-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting imageio==2.19.3
  Using cached imageio-2.19.3-py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)
Collecting importlib-metadata==4.11.4
  Using cached importlib_metadata-4.11.4-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting importlib-resources==5.7.1
  Using cached importlib_resources-5.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
Collecting ipykernel==6.13.0
  Using cached ipykernel-6.13.0-py3-none-any.whl (131 kB)
Collecting ipython==8.3.0
  Using cached ipython-8.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (750 kB)
Collecting ipython-genutils==0.2.0
  Using cached ipython_genutils-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting ipywidgets==7.7.0
  Using cached ipywidgets-7.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (123 kB)
Collecting itsdangerous==2.1.2
  Using cached itsdangerous-2.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting jedi==0.18.1
  Using cached jedi-0.18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.6 MB)
Collecting jinja2==3.1.2
  Using cached Jinja2-3.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting jsonschema==4.5.1
  Using cached jsonschema-4.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (72 kB)
Collecting jupyter==1.0.0
  Using cached jupyter-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.7 kB)
Collecting jupyter-client==7.3.1
  Using cached jupyter_client-7.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (130 kB)
Collecting jupyter-console==6.4.3
  Using cached jupyter_console-6.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting jupyter-core==4.10.0
  Using cached jupyter_core-4.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (87 kB)
Collecting jupyter-dash==0.4.2
  Using cached jupyter_dash-0.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting jupyterlab-pygments==0.2.2
  Using cached jupyterlab_pygments-0.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting jupyterlab-widgets==1.1.0
  Using cached jupyterlab_widgets-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (245 kB)
Collecting keras==2.9.0
  Using cached keras-2.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.6 MB)
Collecting keras-preprocessing==1.1.2
  Using cached Keras_Preprocessing-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Collecting kiwisolver==1.4.2
  Using cached kiwisolver-1.4.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (55 kB)
Collecting libclang==14.0.1
  Using cached libclang-14.0.1-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl (14.2 MB)
Collecting markdown==3.3.7
  Using cached Markdown-3.3.7-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
Collecting markupsafe==2.1.1
  Using cached MarkupSafe-2.1.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (17 kB)

Pip subprocess error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matlabengineforpython==R2020b (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for matlabengineforpython==R2020b

failed

CondaEnvException: Pip failed
```

Comment: Do you have MATLAB R2020b installed?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [condaENVexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62568247/condaenvexception-pip-failed-i-am-getting-a-pip-subprocess-error-when-trying-t).

Try updating conda and pip versions to latest.